# ML Picture Analysis for 3D Camera Position and Aperture-Angle

Tags: 3d

I’m looking to ad an ML image analysis to my web project, where people upload an image with a letter in it and the app recognizes the letter and pulls out a 3D camera position and aperture-angle. I’m not a real programmer myself though understanding it well enough for feature planning etc., want to pick up the path to introduce and to work with a coder to put it up.

Any tips on getting on right track for this task be appreciated )

Frank

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be training the ML algo yourself (which by my guess you're going to need to) you're going to need:

- A large dataset of whatever glyphs you're going to want to detect
- Someone with knowledge of image processing pipelines for augmenting that data. The data of just the glyphs wont be enough, you're going to want to take each glyph and put it at random combinations of different apertures and different positions
- You're going to need to train the neural network with a one hot encoding for the glyphs (one output neuron for each glyph) and then probably one to two neurons each for rotation, angle, etc...

This wont be easy, google, amazon, etc have spent millions of dollars and millions of hours on developing computer vision tech like this, and will take a lot of time to develop and train. Really ask yourself if this feature and all of those components is necessary to you.

You can also have it so that the ML algo only needs to detect the glyph, and use some form of other computer vision/image manipulation techniques (opencv) to manipulate the image back into the glyph and make assumptions of the original camera position based on those transformations. Essentially, see what would need to be done to take the recognized glyph and turn it into the data the app was given. But even then, you'd need an un-transformed version of the recognized glyph for it to work well.

Comment: @Frank If you like it please mark it as an answer (I cant even comment on your post yet I have so little rep)

Answer (score 0):

ok i c. Then i probably better take a non-million-$ path alternative, which would be 3D usage in web.
The users could just mark the perimeters of a square in a photo and then i can basically speaking calculate the scene extents and the cam position.

Question, is there an open source server sided 3D-App that allows for php interaction ?

Resepctively what would be a good way to setup this topic as a task ?